# How to limit excessive CPU usage from guest OS in KVM

Tags: virtualization, xen, kvm-virtualization, central-processing-unit, scheduled-task

On **Xen** it is easy as we have `CreditScheduler` [1], so on a machine with each guest OS sharing only portion of CPU, e.g. 6 guests running on top of a dual core CPU, excessive CPU usage is prohibited.

How to do the same thing on KVM?

[1] http://wiki.xensource.com/xenwiki/CreditScheduler

Answer (score 2, accepted):

KVM doesn't include any such mechanism. However, since each virtual machine is simply a process on the host, they can be managed with standard process utilities such as `nice` or better yet, [cgroups](https://access.redhat.com/knowledge/docs/en-US/Red_Hat_Enterprise_Linux/6/html/Resource_Management_Guide/ch01.html).